# Primefaces - how to set file to upload

Tags: primefaces

I want to use Primefaces fileupload, this is my jsf page:

```
 <h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form">  

    <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" value="#{fileUploadController.file}" mode="simple"/>  

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"  
                                 actionListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}" />               
 </h:form>
```

This is my bean:

```
package FileUploadController;


import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadController {  

    private UploadedFile file; 

    public UploadedFile getFile() {  
        return file;  
    }  

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {  
        this.file = file;  
    }  

    public void upload() {  
        if(file != null) {  
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

And here are the required dependencies for prim. fileupload, pom.xml (I using maven project):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>     
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>portlet-api</groupId>
     <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I would like set the `UploadedFile` file. When I click on Submit button upload method is called correctly, but `UploadedFile` file is still null, is not setted to choosed file. How can I set this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [enctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype) attribute `enctype="multipart/form"` is invalid. The `enctype` attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server.

According to the PrimeFaces documentation (page 183.) the `enctype` attribute should be defined as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, in your case:

```
<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</h:form>
```

Comment: @brano You are welcome! Mark this post as answer (by clicking on the checkmark on the left side) if it helped you in solving your problem. See [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? – akoskm